# doFilter in the formfilter is not calling the next filter (LoginFilter)

Tags: java, struct, websphere, security

I am facing the problem while doFilter in the formfilter is called. I am expecting this to call the next filter i.e.. LoginFilter, but it's neither returning an exception not calling the next filter class.

*Web.xml***

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <display-name>LoginFilter</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <filter-class>com.struts.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>FormFilter</filter-name>
    <display-name>FormFilter</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <filter-class>com.struts.FormFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FormFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secured/j_security_check</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FormFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>secured/j_security_check</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FormFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_security_check</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FormFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>j_security_check</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/mainmenu.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Once the j_security_check is done, the control will call the FormFilter call and after that it should call LoginFilter, the it should be redirected to the main menu. But it's not happening. 
Can any one please guide me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Post your form filter code and any reason why you're having multiple mappings for almost the same URLs?

Comment: Will that multiple mappings cause a problem ?? That's the same flow we are using for different projects, but this is one failing...

Comment: Can't say that for sure but if you put println in filter and that prints multiple times then your filter is obviously getting fired multiple times which isn't what you would ideally want. Not saying that this is the main issue but this isn't the right thing to do either. But your filter code is required to see what's breaking the chain.